# Auto-suggestion list box

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, autocomplete

Hi i have the following auto-suggestion box set up and i want to select the outputs with keyboard and mouse. how can i do that?

Javascript code:

```
 function showResult(string) {

     if (string.lenght==0) {
         document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
         document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
         return;
     }
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
         // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
         xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     } else {
         //code for IE6, IE5
         xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
         }
         document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
         document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border = "1px solid #A5ACB2";
     }
     xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?q=" + string,true);
     xmlhttp.send();
}
```

PHP code:

```
$xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
//$xmlDoc->load("test.xml");
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");

//$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('datas');

//get the q parameter from URL
$q = $_GET["q"];
if (strlen($q) > 0) {   
    foreach ($xml->datas as $a) {
        $var = $a->attributes();
        $domain = stristr($var,$q);
        echo $domain."\n";
        echo "<br/>";
    }
    if (strlen($domain) == 0) {
        echo "no results";
    }
```

Everything works fine at this point. But I don't know how to interact with the list.

Comment: Doubt this is the problem, but you've spelled "length" wrong in `string.lenght`

Comment: I would suggest you to use jquery's autocomplete plugin (http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) available from jqueryui.com rather than reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to user some proper autocomplete jQuery. You can search by "autocomplete jquery" and find out a jQuery which fits your requirements. If you want to write your own code then you can make functions which work for mouse and keyboard events:

```
txtSearchBox.keyup(function (e) {

    // get keyCode (window.event is for IE)
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || window.event.keyCode;
    var lastSearch = txtSearchBox.val();

    // check for an ENTER 
    if (keyCode == 13) {
        OnEnterClick();
        return;
    }

    // check an treat up and down arrows
    if (OnUpDownClick(keyCode)) {
        return;
    }

    // check for an ESC
    if (keyCode == 27) {
        clearResults();
        return;
    }
});
```

And then in "OnEnterClick()", "OnUpDownClick()" and "OnUpDownClick()" you can display what you want like:

```
function OnUpDownClick(keyCode) {
    if(keyCode == 40 || keyCode == 38){

        if(keyCode == 38){ // keyUp
            // Do something keyUp event
        } else { // keyDown
            // Do something for keyDown event
        }

        return true;
    } else {
        // reset
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answers i will look into them and try it out

Comment: I was able to find a good example and work with it although it has some problems. For other reading this post. Go to this web page. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget/ . Thank you all for your answers